# Torque converter

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, f-150, transmission-fluid, torque-converter

I accidentally put qt power steering fluid with qt transmission fluid in torque converter. Put torque converter into transmission hooked transmission to motor then realized. PSF ATF. Will it be ok to go ahead and add rest of ATF to rest of Transmission run for a few minutes then drain and start fresh. If how do I drain a torque converter. To plug noticed on TC. Or should I just drop transmission. Both fluids are for hydraulic parts. One for gears one for movement. Both lubricants. What is on inside of TC that PSF would ruin??  Ok. I’m at loss. I’ve researched and I have found where u can mix in transmission but drain asap. But no where can I find anything about TC. It should all mix after awhile of starting the motor. Oooo I have not turned the motor over yet. Trying
G to figure out what I should do. Ty for anyone’s advise. Old school or new school. Ford 2008 f150 V6 4.2 A/T RWD